# Сумма первых n значений, удовлетворяющих условию, в MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

В Интернете ничего не нашел по вопросу ниже, решил написать здесь.

Имеется таблица следующего вида:

```
                Январь      Февраль     Март      ...
              План  Факт  План  Факт  План  Факт  ...
Показатель 1  10    23    14    15    20    25    ...
Показатель 2  15    24    14    17    21    17    ...
...
```

Необходимо в конце таблицы посчитать, к примеру, сумму показателей за первые шесть месяцев отдельно по факту и отельно по плану.

Если пользоваться формулой СУММЕСЛИ, то выйдет, что для каждой отдельной суммы в зависимости от количества месяцев, которые нужно учесть, необходимо задавать разные диапазоны условия и суммирования. Если же пользоваться СУММЕСЛИМН и учитывать месяцы, то формула выходит длинная и ее придется прописывать при добавлении каждого последующего месяца.

Есть ли возможность создать формулу без дополнительных ячеек, которая будет учитывать условие (план или факт), при этом принимая диапазоны значений и условия целого года, а также количество первых месяцев, необходимых для расчета?

В идеале на выходе иметь формулу типа =СУММАПЕРВЫХN(числ_строка(Янв-Дек);строка_условия(Янв-Дек);"План"(или "Факт");количество_мес_с_первого), но понимаю, что такого нет. Как это можно реализовать иначе?

Спасибо!

Comment: Да написать VBA-функцию, которая принимает массив и отдаёт результат, и всё.

Comment: @Akina, да, но этим будут другие люди пользоваться, которым с макросами будет сложно. Формулой было бы удобней.

Comment: Не понял, а в чём проблема-то? эти "другие люди" неспособны ввести формулу, если функция в ней не встроенная, а определённая пользователем? или они неспособны скопипастить код в модуль, не повредив его?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что последними 2 столбцами, у вас будут столбцы план и факт, в которых будут суммироваться данные (от первого до последнего месяца), и это просто должно работать при вставке/удалении месяцев, или там должен быть еще какой-то параметр, типа заполнены 12 месяцев а выбрать надо за 4 первых?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то такой вариант:

1. Если просто в конце таблицы 2 столбца, в которых считается отдельно план и факт, но при это можно вставлять или удалять месяцы
   ячейка `J3`:

   =СУММЕСЛИ($B$2:ИНДЕКС($B$2:$BB$2;1;СТОЛБЕЦ()-1);"План";$B3:ИНДЕКС($B3:$BB3;1;СТОЛБЕЦ()-1))

`K3` тоже самое только меняем План на Факт, ну и далее копируем вниз

2. Если надо именно считать за определенное количество месяцев
   `L3`:

   =СУММЕСЛИ($B$2:ИНДЕКС($B$2:$BB$2;1;МИН(СТОЛБЕЦ()-1;2*$M$1));"План";$B3:ИНДЕКС($B3:$BB3;1;МИН(СТОЛБЕЦ()-1;2*$M$1)))

`M3` так же меняем План на Факт

Небольшие пояснения:

если ИНДЕКС не просто введена в ячейку после знака =, как обычно, а используется как финальная часть ссылки на диапазон после двоеточия, то выдает она уже не содержимое ячейки, а ее адрес

т.е. для первого варианта `$B$2:ИНДЕКС($B$2:$BB$2;1;СТОЛБЕЦ()-1)` - вернет ссылку на диапазон от $B$2 до предыдущего столбца, где написана эта формула, т.е. $B2:I2

Во втором варианте функция МИН служит выбора минимального значения между количеством заполненных месяцев и требуемых в отчете, иначе будет циклическая ссылка, если заполнено 2 месяца а мы хотим сделать выборку за 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Tunker, большое спасибо! Мне как раз второй вариант и нужен, так как таблицы готовые.

Answer (score 0):

В *Z3*, копировать на два столбца:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ($B$2:ИНДЕКС($B$2:$Y$2;$AA$1*2);Z$2;$B3:ИНДЕКС($B3:$Y3;$AA$1*2))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA, спасибо!